# Can you call a SQL Stored Procedure that returns a record set and have those values loaded into variables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please consider the following SQL Server table and stored procedure.

```
create table customers(cusnum int, cusname varchar(50))

insert into customers(cusnum, cusname) values(1, 'Ken')
insert into customers(cusnum, cusname) values (2, 'Violet') --The Wife

create procedure getcus 
  @cusnum int
as 
Begin
   select cusname
   from customers (nolock)
   where cusnum = @cusnum
End
```

You know how you can write T-SQL code like this:

```
declare @cusname varchar(50)

select @cusname = cusname
from customers 
where cusnum = 1
```

Can I do this with my stored procedure?

for example the code would look like this:

```
declare @cusnum int
declare @cusname varchar(50)

set @cusnum = 1

exec @cusname = cusname pbogetcus @cusnum
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would happen if your stored procedure returned two rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't return values like that.

You need to use OutputParameters: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

EDIT:

This might be a better link:

[SQL Team](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data)

Check out the section about midway down: **Using OUTPUT variables**